# How to find the group presentation of $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to find the group presentation of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, where $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is direct product of groups.

Comment: Hint: Show that if $F$ is the free group of $n$ elements then $F/[F,F]$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$, and thus isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z^n}$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\langle a_1,\dots,a_n|a_ia_j=a_ja_i, i,j=1\dots,n\rangle$.  Presentations are not unique, btw.